# Where can I *very* cheaply store a car with a dangerous gas leak until covid lifts and I can work towards a fix?

Tags: camry, long-term-storage

I have an old car with a gas leak in a gas line (along with *severe* corrosion issues). I've figured out a good plan for fixing these issues, but it involves towing it across several states with a destination that is among the worst in the country with covid at the present, and visiting that area for an extended period of time — so it would be incredibly reckless to do so at this time. As such, I need to find a way to store this car cheaply, safely, and legally until then (it might be spring when I can get vaccinated, or it could be a year).

I don't have a garage that I can keep it in, and if I did it would probably be unwise since the gas leak is a fire hazard, and I don't want to cause a structure fire (or a car fire, for that matter). Keeping it in the driveway is a no-go too, since the area has laws against unregistered cars being visible in public and I need to spend what little money I have on registration of a different car that I can actually drive in the meantime. Family members who have enclosed garages have refused to help since they're worried about a structure fire, and one who doesn't live in an area that restricts registration is worried that that fire hazard on a driveway isn't justified (e.g. if some spark ends up on the roadway near the house, that could be a big problem).

As such, I ask how can I very cheaply (ideally for free) store this car until I can get a covid vaccine and do what I need to do to fix it? Although I lack much money, this car has incredible sentimental importance to me, so I *really* don't want to sell it to a junkyard (I would be willing to pay some non-trivial money, but I don't have it.) — although I do plan to call one to see if they'll let me keep it there, without being for sale, in the meantime, as they are equipped for this sort of thing.

Comment: Why haven’t you emptied the fuel tank so that there is no fuel to leak?

Comment: @HandyHowie That's part of the plan, although I was keeping it there for now so I could drive it to the junkyard if storage failed. The fuel has apparently "saturated" the fuel lines, which makes it impossible to remove even close to all of it.

Answer (score 1):

Drain the gas out of the tank and lines.

However, that is not a perfect solution as vapor will still exist in the tank, but it will prevent the gas from spreading over / into the ground.

As for where you leave it then that is a solution you need to sort - does it meet the standards to be left in the public road? If not, your drive? A spare drive of a neighbor?

Answer (score 1):

- Disconnect the battery
- Drain the gas tank
- Disconnect (even better, remove) the gas tank
- Fill the gas tank with water (this will displace any gas vapor - do
  it in an open area). Up to you if you empty the water out or not. It
  may cause more rust, but hey - rust doesn't burn.

Now talk again to friends and family about storing it at their places; there is no gas or gas vapor in the car, so it's not a fire hazard. Just hope that they don't know that rust can jump six feet... :p

Answer (score 1):

I can't see storage coming out cheaper than registration.

Drain the tank that makes it safe, or at-least safe-er

Then throw a tarp, or car-cover over it, or build a temporary fence behind it That prevents it from being visibly unregistered.